# My Secret Cabal

Tags: pattern, word-property

I'm in a cabal so secret and nefarious that very few of its members even know they are members. Our ranks include:

1. Former Seattle police chief **Carmen Best**
2. Physician and diplomat **Deborah Birx**
3. Writer **Edward Abbey**
4. Washington state representative **Frank Chopp**
5. Model **Kate Moss**
6. Postmaster General **Louis DeJoy**
7. Rock climber **Lynn Hill**
8. Businessman and philanthropist **Michael Dell**
9. Nobel laureate and Secretary of Energy **Steven Chu**
10. Texas senator **Ted Cruz**

We haven't gotten together in a while though, and I was going to arrange a virtual meeting to catch up and generally be sinister. Unfortunately, I've lost the complete list of members, and I don't want to make anyone feel slighted. Can you help by reminding me of the names of at least 5 more members of my cabal?

(Be sure to use a spoiler block when you reveal our initiation rules in your answer.  It is, after all, a *secret cabal*. Ssh!)

Comment: Can I just check that Kate Moss is *definitely* a member?

Comment: @Astralbee yes, Kate has been a member since 1974.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could invite

- Steve Abel
- Emma Bell
- Margaret Chin
- Raymond Dehn
- Vitaly Efimov

Which would be members of your cabal as their

> surname's letters are in alphabetical order - as is your own - Hirst :)

Comment: Well done, I'm especially looking forward to hatching some evil plots with Vitaly!

Comment: Do puzzle has an unique solution?

Comment: @Nick no -- there are many thousands of possible cabal members, including a number of famous people not yet mentioned.